# What does <<= mean in java

Tags: java

I'm working on a program for class and was asked to figure out what <<= means and I found that << means a left shift of bits.  I'm not sure what a left shift of bits is either though

Comment: Where do you think might you look to find this information? Perhaps a reference for the Java programming language?

Comment: What does `+=` mean?

Comment: `Left shift AND assignment operator` - `C <<= 2 is same as C = C << 2` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

Comment: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts)

Comment: This is why we need a "Please perform a search before asking a question" flag reason.

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to += or -= or similar operators. The operator << makes a copy of the variable and shifts it left. You must then assign this to a variable or use it in some way. The code:

```
x << 2;
```

does nothing. You must use this value in some way:

```
x = x << 2;
x <<= 2;
```

These are equivalent statements.

Answer (score 0):

A left shift operator simply moves every bit of a variable to the left. Say we have defined the following variables:

```
char c = 5;
char d = 5;
```

lets say char is a 8-bit variable. In this case, c and d's binary form would look like this:

```
00000101
```

When a left shift is performed on c, every bit would move to the left:

```
c <<= 1;     // now c = 00001010
d <<= 2;     // now d = 00010100
```

Comment: Ok this is making some sense, so what is the effect of shifting each bit?  will c and d both still equal 5?